# Why is this non-homogenous whereas the other one isn't?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My understanding of classifying PDEs as homogeneous or non-homogeneous stems from the following definition, taken ad verbatim.

> Linear equations can be further classified as homogeneous for which the dependent variable (and its derivatives) appear in terms with degree **exactly** one, and non-homogeneous which may contain terms which only depend on the independent variable.

Consider the two PDEs below.

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}= \sin x$$

$$u_{xx}+u_{xy}+u_{yy}=e^x u + \cos x$$

According to the solutions, the top equation is non-homogeneous whereas the bottom equation is homogeneous.

I understand that the $\sin x$ prevents homogeneity in the first equation, but why would the $\cos x$ not prevent homogeneity in the second one then?

Comment: You are right there I think.

Comment: These are both non-homogeneous equations.